# Adding state to an external variable in React

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state

Suppose I have a file called Columns.js and I am exporting an object cols = {//some data} in it. Now, say I am importing that object in file Widget.js. Now, can I add that variable to the state of the react component?

I want to do this way as the object is too big. Also, i have tried cloning it but it doesn't work.

Columns.js

```
const cols = {A:'a',B:'b'}
export default cols;
```

Widget.js

```
import cols from './Columns';
export default function Widget(){
// here i want to make my variable cols have a state

//some code which uses cols and changes it
}
```

Comment: Some code of what you have would help us help you..

Comment: It's possible yes.

Comment: @CisumInas Have edited, please give a look at it :)

Comment: @kevin added some code

Comment: you can use a customhook, store data in there and use it

Comment: @YashTailor why do you need state? You can just use data directly

Comment: @suhailahmed u mean a custom method that returns it?

Comment: @kevin the updates are not getting reflected

Comment: @YashTailor yes, you can read about custom hooks here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as using spread syntax for the object to copy it inside state object in your useState call (if we talk about functional component).
So the code should look like this:

```js
import cols from './Columns';
export default function Widget(){
// here i want to make my variable cols have a state
  const [state, setState] = useState({...cols});

//some code which uses cols and changes it
}
```

Now your `state` variable holds the same data as the `cols` and you can use it in your ui and change with `setState`.

Comment: I can use setState in another file too right? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use setState in another component by passing it down as a prop